# After updating Angular 14 to 15 getting sass mixn error

Tags: angular

1. I've updated angular 14 to 15 and material to 15.
2. ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
3. delete node_modules and package-lock files and npm cache clean --force then reinstall it.
4. in ng build or ng serve I'm getting SassError: Undefined mixin.
5. npm install -g sass-migrator and npm rebuild node-sass
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqBpd.png)
6. error is

```
./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
╷
69 │ @include mat-form-field-theme($formfield-primary-theme);
│ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
src\configurator-styles\configurator-material.scss 69:1  @import
src\styles.scss 7:9                                      root stylesheet

./src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
╷
69 │ @include mat-form-field-theme($formfield-primary-theme);
│ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
src\configurator-styles\configurator-material.scss 69:1  @import
src\styles.scss 7:9
```

Answer (score -1):

Theming in angular material 15 was changed, now you have to style components in this way:

```scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

// Define a light theme
$theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette),
   accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette),
 ),
));

// Apply the dark theme by default
@include mat.core-theme($theme);
@include mat.form-field-theme($theme);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer error gone, but mat-form-field css like padding and sizes are changed.

Comment: I guess you have rewritten them previously and due to styling change your custom styling is not matching proper elements anymore, so you have to adjust it too. FYI: Thoroughly answering questions is time-consuming. If your question is solved, say thank you by accepting the solution that is best for your needs.